# How to format code in MavensMate?

Tags: apex, formatting, mavensmate

Does anyone how to re-format code in MavensMate? If a plugin going hand in hand with MM exists, that'd be great as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using [astyle](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter). You can install in in sublimetext via package install.